# Can MongoDB Compass be embedded into a Web Page?

Tags: database, mongodb, embed, html, mongodb-compass

Would it be possible to embed the GUI from MongoDB Compass into a Web Page with a static URL and full access to the MongoDB database? For instance could it be displayed on a Confluence page and if it's possible, would this require an extra license or any other implication? I'm asking because the Client-Side of this project can't be forced to download some form of software in order to access the reports generated from Compass.

As a side note: If anyone knows of a MongoDB extension used to genrate visual reports that CAN be embedded into a confluence page please let me know.